# Splinting one cell to different cells

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape

I have read csv file, which contain data in below format:

```
A   0.1
B   0.2
C   .1,.2,.4,.6
D   .1,.2,.4,.6
E   0.2
```

I want to set this in like:

```
A   B   C   D   E
0.1 0.2 0.1 0.1 0.2
        0.2 0.2 
        0.4 0.4 
        0.6 0.6
```

I am using code:

```
test <- read.csv("test.csv")

test_t <- setNames(data.frame(t(test[,-1])), test[,1])
```

which is giving  error:

> Error in setNames(data.frame(t(test[, -1])), test[, 1]) : 
>     'names' attribute [4] must be the same length as the vector [1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using:

```
library(splitstackshape)
dcast(cSplit(df, 'V2', ',','long'), rowid(V1) ~ V1)[,-1]
```

gives:

> ```
>      A   B   C   D   E
> 1: 0.1 0.2 0.1 0.1 0.2
> 2:  NA  NA 0.2 0.2  NA
> 3:  NA  NA 0.4 0.4  NA
> 4:  NA  NA 0.6 0.6  NA
> ```

---

A solution without extra packages:

```
splt <- strsplit(as.character(df$V2),',')
df2 <- data.frame(V1 = rep(df$V1, lengths(splt)),
                  V2 = as.numeric(unlist(splt)),
                  id = unlist(lapply(splt, seq_along)))

df3 <- reshape(df2, idvar = 'id', timevar = 'V1', direction = 'wide')
```

which gives a similar result:

> ```
> > df3
>   V2.A V2.B V2.C V2.D V2.E
> 1  0.1  0.2  0.1  0.1  0.2
> 4   NA   NA  0.2  0.2   NA
> 5   NA   NA  0.4  0.4   NA
> 6   NA   NA  0.6  0.6   NA
> ```

If you want to get the exact same column-names as in the first solution:

```
names(df3) <- gsub('V2.', '', names(df3), fixed = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks Jaap, but I should have mentioned that I will be using this code with rengine api, where all the libraries are not available, so was looking for solution without any additional library though I can use plyr, zoo or reshape as these libraries are available to use.

Comment: @AnuragSharma added a complete base R solution